# How to set my own server as a CDN for hosting JS and JSON for 3rd parties

Tags: javascript, http-headers, cdn

As simple as the title goes :

I have a js library I would to be accessible for 3rd party end users, without having to worry about CORS.
Are there any free js libraries hosting services?

Following that, if I have json content I want accessible by 3rd party end users, how can I do it?

Comment: If your project is open-source, jsDelivr is a CDN that hosts anything published to the npm registry for free.

Comment: I'll check. thanks

Comment: No worries. I didn't realize until I looked again just now, but they also host GitHub projects- you wouldn't necessarily have to publish to npm if your project is on GitHub.

Comment: That answered my question, and gave me a working solution. should this be written as an answer I would gladly mark it as the correct one

Comment: I'll take some of that rep, then! /laugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsDeliver](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) is a CDN that hosts GitHub projects and npm packages for free, provided the code is open-source JavaScript.